# How to dismiss a view controller by swiping left corner and keep view floating or animating in case swipe is not complete?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How to achieve something like this where you open view controller which expands from a cell and can be closed by swiping only at left side of the screen with animation. Right now Im focussed on only the part of dismissing the view controller with animation where its like a drag, you swipe from left side and if you hold your finger, the view stays floating and if you leave, it goes back and does not close and if you continue it will dismiss.

Here's an example from App Store app. You can check in App Store yourself.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in second image, view controller is floating and not closed, you can either close it or stop swiping and it will go back to full screen. Please take a look in the App Store app for any cell in main page.

How to add this type of gesture to dismiss any view controller?

Comment: If you drag and it animates more as you drag further, and releasing your finger before completing the drag, it's a pan gesture, not a swipe gesture (As Apple defines those terms.) A pan gesture is a continuous gesture and a swipe gesture is a one-shot gesture.

You should look at `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, not `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: oh I was looking all over internet for swipe gesture. Thanks for clarifying